# Drawn line is not smooth in Jetpack Compose path

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-canvas

I'm trying to draw an scale using Jetpack Compose version 1.5.4. So far so good, but my problem comes when I try to draw the weight indicator, which feels like it has some kind of aliasing.

[image]

As you can see, it should be a smooth triangle. What is wrong here?

My code is the following for that specific indicator:

```
drawPath(
    path = Path().apply {
        reset()
        arcTo(
            rect = Rect(
                center = scaleCenter,
                radius = innerRadius
            ),
            startAngleDegrees = 269.5f,
            sweepAngleDegrees = 1f,
            forceMoveTo = false
        )
        lineTo(
            x = scaleCenter.x + innerRadius * cos((3 * PI.toFloat()) / 2),
            y = scaleCenter.y + innerRadius * sin((3 * PI.toFloat()) / 2) - style.scaleIndicatorLength.toPx()
        )
        close()
    },
    color = style.scaleIndicatorColor
)
```

Answer (score 0):

It seemed that I had the `drawPath` inside the`for` loop that I had to draw the scale lines. Since (I guess) the lines are limited by the pixel size, drawing over an over that path caused it to have that shape.

Now it is much smoother (not perfect thought, but I think it's as good as it can get)

[image]